# Number of hands played by a November Nine?

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, hand-history, wsop

What is roughly the number of hands that a player has to play during the tournament to reach the final table of the WSOP main event? Let us say over the past five years.

Comment: Do you mean, on average, how many hands does a niner have to play to get to the FT? Also, why would you want to know this?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. I edited my question a little bit by adding "in the tournament".

Comment: For the reason, I think I am mostly curious...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I had to close this since it's not a good question for this site. Answers to this (correct or not) provide no added value for someone's poker knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very rough estimation based on this year. 35 levels passed = 70 hours of play. If they played 20 hands an hour this makes 1400 hands. For the last 5 years the number of players is roughly the same so I would guess the number of hands should be similar.

Answer (score -4):

It depends a lot on the origin of the player. Chris moneymaker for example won the main event without having prior experience, so I would guess he played no more than 2500 hands (that's just a hard guess, I don't know Chris moneymaker more than that and he might easily have played more than that before)

A professional poker player on the Internet could have played 3 years 25000 hands a month, for a total of almost 1 million hands

Comment: Sorry, my question was probably ambiguous, but I meant then number of hands during the tournament. I have edited my question to make it hopefully clearer.

Comment: I think the Moneymaker comment is surely false. Just because he was an "unknown" at the time doesn't mean he didn't play a lot of hands on PokerStars where he won the satellite. He probably didn't play a lot of hands by modern online multitabling standards, but surely he had played tens of thousands of hands leading up to his 2003 WSOP appearance.

Comment: And I'm also curious about your math. It's terribly wrong. If you play 3 years at 25K hands per month, that's 900K hands. Not 2 billion. In order to play 2 billion hands, you've got a serious task on your hands. Assuming you could play 1 hand per second all day, every day, that would still take over 63 years of 24/7 play. I think it's safe to say that no human has played that many hands.

Comment: I really hate to downvote anyone but there's just so many things wrong with this answer. None of the numbers in it make sense or are even close!

Comment: Sorry for the bad numbers, i'm not English native so i mixed up with million and billion. I also did bad calculus, do i understand the downvotes. I have now updated my question